# Failed Tensorflow Lite conversion: Unsupported data type in placeholder op

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

System information:
Mac OS Mojave

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):
pip install tensorflow

TensorFlow version (or github SHA if from source):
1.12

I am trying to convert a simple convolutional tensorflow model to tensorflow lite. I already have it in SavedModel format. But when I try to run the convert util on the saved model, I get:

`RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b"2018-12-30 15:40:54.449737: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:189] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 2\n2018-12-30 15:40:54.450020: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:2137] Check failed: status.ok() Unexpected value forattribute 'T'. Expected 'DT_FLOAT'\n"`

To save the model, I have:

`// model is an Estimator instance
def export(model):
  model.export_saved_model("tmp/export", serving_input_receiver_fn)`

and:

`def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  features = { 'x': tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 100, 100, 1], dtype=tf.as_dtype(np.int32)) }
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, features)`

Input dtype is np.int32, so I attempt to cast that to a tf type here.

I can attach the full model def on request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was not in the placeholder op itself, but in the model declaration. I was using a float64 input type. Switching to float32, and setting dtype=float32 in the placeholder, solved my issue.